# How to send and receive data using BluetoothManager.framework private API on iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, iphone-privateapi

These Days I'm working on a project in which we need to connect an non-MFI Bluetooth Device to iPhone,and that device doesn't support to be an BLE peripheral client, so we have to do this on classical bluetooth.

I managed to paired and connected the device to iPhone using `BluetoothManager.framework` with the guide of the [demo project BeeTee](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee)

But I don't known how to send and recv data, I can't find the API in the class-dump headers.

It seems that the answer lies in this three `structs:BTAccessoryManagerImpl` & `BTSessionImpl` & `BTDeviceImpl` ,but I can't get the definition of them.

```
@class NSMutableDictionary;

struct BTSessionImpl { };
struct BTDeviceImpl { };


@interface BluetoothManager : NSObject {
    struct BTAccessoryManagerImpl { } *_accessoryManager;
    BOOL _audioConnected;
    int _available;
    NSMutableDictionary *_btAddrDict;
    NSMutableDictionary *_btDeviceDict;
    struct BTDiscoveryAgentImpl { } *_discoveryAgent;
    struct BTLocalDeviceImpl { } *_localDevice;
    struct BTPairingAgentImpl { } *_pairingAgent;
    BOOL _scanningEnabled;
    BOOL _scanningInProgress;
    unsigned int _scanningServiceMask;
    struct BTSessionImpl *_session; // struct BTSessionImpl { } *_session;

}

+ (int)lastInitError;
+ (id)sharedInstance;

- (struct BTAccessoryManagerImpl *)_accessoryManager; // - (struct BTAccessoryManagerImpl { }*)_accessoryManager;
- (void)_advertisingChanged;
- (BOOL)_attach:(id)arg1;
- (void)_cleanup:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)_connectabilityChanged;
- (void)_connectedStatusChanged;
- (void)_discoveryStateChanged;
- (BOOL)_onlySensorsConnected;
- (void)_postNotification:(id)arg1;
- (void)_postNotificationWithArray:(id)arg1;
- (void)_powerChanged;
- (void)_removeDevice:(id)arg1;
- (void)_restartScan;
- (void)_scanForServices:(unsigned int)arg1 withMode:(int)arg2;
- (void)_setScanState:(int)arg1;
- (BOOL)_setup:(struct BTSessionImpl*)arg1;
- (void)acceptSSP:(int)arg1 forDevice:(id)arg2;
- (id)addDeviceIfNeeded:(struct BTDeviceImpl *)arg1;
- (BOOL)audioConnected;
- (BOOL)available;
- (void)cancelPairing;
- (void)connectDevice:(id)arg1 withServices:(unsigned int)arg2;
- (void)connectDevice:(id)arg1;
- (BOOL)connectable;
- (BOOL)connected;
- (id)connectedDevices;
- (id)connectingDevices;
- (void)dealloc;
- (BOOL)devicePairingEnabled;
- (BOOL)deviceScanningEnabled;
- (BOOL)deviceScanningInProgress;
- (void)enableTestMode;
- (BOOL)enabled;
- (void)endVoiceCommand:(id)arg1;
- (id)init;
- (BOOL)isAnyoneAdvertising;
- (BOOL)isAnyoneScanning;
- (BOOL)isDiscoverable;
- (BOOL)isServiceSupported:(unsigned int)arg1;
- (int)localDeviceSupportsService:(unsigned int)arg1;
- (id)pairedDevices;
- (void)postNotification:(id)arg1;
- (void)postNotificationName:(id)arg1 object:(id)arg2 error:(id)arg3;
- (void)postNotificationName:(id)arg1 object:(id)arg2;
- (int)powerState;
- (BOOL)powered;
- (void)resetDeviceScanning;
- (void)scanForConnectableDevices:(unsigned int)arg1;
- (void)scanForServices:(unsigned int)arg1;
- (void)setAudioConnected:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)setConnectable:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)setDevicePairingEnabled:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)setDeviceScanningEnabled:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)setDiscoverable:(BOOL)arg1;
- (BOOL)setEnabled:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)setPincode:(id)arg1 forDevice:(id)arg2;
- (BOOL)setPowered:(BOOL)arg1;
- (void)showPowerPrompt;
- (void)startVoiceCommand:(id)arg1;
- (void)unpairDevice:(id)arg1;
- (BOOL)wasDeviceDiscovered:(id)arg1;

@end
```

Comment: How you connected to the bluetooth using the Bee Tee Bluetooth Framework

Answer (score 4):

Reading or writing data on a bluetooth connection can be done over a virtual file `/dev/ttys*`. After a successful connection to the right service, you need to call `BTDeviceGetComPortForService` from `MobileBluetooth.framework`, that will retrieve the correct file path. A full example with the right header file you will find [here](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-bluetooth/source/browse/btGpsServer/Classes/BluetoothContext.mm).

Open the file and read or write to it. That's it.
To read data asynchronously you might have [look here](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-bluetooth/source/browse/btGpsServer/gps_thread.m) at the methods `openTty` and `readCompletionNotification`.

This worked for me on a jailbroken iOS 7 iPhone. I would like to hear if someone else has success with this solution.

Comment: Thanks A lot! alu.

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to connect to a bluetooth device using iOS 10.0, i achieve that using Bluetooth Manager but i need to send/receive data and i don't know how to use MobileBluetooth.framework. Do you know how can i retrieve data from the device? Thanks ;)